# Can I change Emacs Doc-view font?

Tags: pdf, fonts, emacs

I'm learning Emacs and lisp environment, doc-view is very good solution for viewing pdf files. I want to change font of doc-view because I don't see some characters clearly.

How can I change the font for doc-view?

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What characters don't you see clearly?

Comment: for example, on the picture I uploaded, bold characters touched each other

Comment: Isn't it the case that the font is specified in the PDF file itself? DocVIew just converts each page into an image and displays them, so it cannot change the document font - at least, AFAIK.

Comment: I solved problem, we need to change resolution
it helps :
 
(require 'doc-view)
(setq doc-view-resolution 144)

Comment: Note that there is a dedicated Emacs site - https://emacs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved problem,

we need to change resolution it helps :

> (require 'doc-view)
> (setq doc-view-resolution 144)

Comment: You can "Accept" your own answer if you wish.